# Is it better to fly or to be better at beating spell resistance?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, sorcerer

I'm a sorcerer planning for down the road.

I have the [Celestial bloodline](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/celestial-bloodline/).

At level 9 I have the option to get the bloodline ability Wings of Heaven:

> Wings of Heaven (Su): At 9th level, you can sprout feathery wings and
>   fly for a number of minutes per day equal to your sorcerer level, with
>   a speed of 60 feet and good maneuverability. This duration does not
>   need to be consecutive, but it must be used in 1 minute increments.

In place of that I can get the bloodline mutation [Blood Piercing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodline-mutations/blood-piercing/):

> When you cast a bloodrager or sorcerer spell that deals damage,
>   creatures affected by the spell reduce their energy resistance and
>   spell resistance against the spell’s effects by an amount equal to
>   your Strength or Charisma modifier, whichever is higher.

Is it better to get the Wings of Heaven, or to get Blood Piercing and the spell [Fly](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fly/) at level 9?

Comment: Can the question provide the campaign's elevator pitch? Evaluating two such disparate abilities in a vacuum is really difficult—I mean, since they're available at the same level, even the abilities' designers were unsure which was better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flight is better by a ***colossal*** margin.

“When you cast a bloodrager or sorcerer spell that deals damage,” is already a pretty niche case—you shouldn’t be doing that very often. Sorcerer spells are vastly more effective at battlefield control, debuffs, or buffs than they are at dealing damage directly. *Haste* will typically offer far more damage than any blast will, for example. You might want *a* blasting spell among your spells known, but probably not more than one, and usually you will have better things to do with your actions and spell slots.

On top of that, reducing spell and energy resistance is not all that valuable. You are far better off using more-reliable spells that are SR: No and don’t deal energy damage at all. For that matter, when possibly, favor spells that have no save; a ranged touch attack is easy and some spells don’t even need that. There is just nothing a typical creature can do about *solid fog*, for instance. Moreover, even if you want to deal energy damage to things, spell resistance and energy resistance aren’t that common. That all adds up to this class feature not getting used a whole lot of the time.

In contrast, flight is one of the most important abilities in the game. If you have it while your foes don’t, you have literally-infinitely as many options as they do. You can move to positions they simply cannot. You can dictate so much about the battle. And, on the flip side, if enemies do have flight, you very much need it—because otherwise you are the one with infinitely fewer options. Every character ever needs to figure out some way to get into the air by mid levels. Even in dungeons with low ceilings, flight still protects you from pitfalls, most difficult or hazardous terrain, pressure plates, and so on.

Honestly, my biggest concern with wings of heaven is waiting until 9th—you should get *fly* at **6th level**, and then swap it out at 10th. You will want to use flight as much as you possibly can. You will feel limited by wings of heaven’s usage limitations, wish you had more of it. At some point, some permanent form of flight might overtake wings of heaven, and that will be a shame—but blood piercing won’t be something you miss much even then.

The only reason to ever consider blood piercing in this situation is if you are consciously avoiding flight, as part of a gentlemen’s agreement among the players and GM that the PCs won’t fly and the GM will design encounters accordingly. There is a lot of merit to such a campaign, because flight is messy, complicated, and incredibly powerful in game-warping ways.